# sumar la cantidad de dos tablas mysql con php desde consulta select

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Tengo 3 tablas:

- venta
- detalle_venta
- Distribucion

En venta tengo las escenciales (idventa, idplaza).

En detalle_venta tengo (iddetalle, idventa, idarticulo, cantidad) y en distribucion tengo(id_dist, idventa, id_plaza, id_cliente, id_articulo, cantidad_dist).

Estas tablas se relacionan por ventas a proveedores y luego en plaza los estos los distribuyen a clientes segun plaza. el problema es el siguiente deseo mostrar una tabla que relacione las 3 tablas y muestre la bodega o el saldo de articulo no distribuido por plaza(proveedor). Es decir que la venta salen 20 y si se distribuyen a los clientes solo 15 me quedaria 5 en la bodega de esa plaza. mi Consulta sql es esta:

```
SELECT  v.idventa,
    v.idplaza,
    dv.idarticulo, 
    dv.iddetalle_venta,
    dv.idventa,
    d.id_dist,
    d.id_plaza,
    d.id_articulo,
    d.id_venta,
    (SUM((SUM(dv.cantidad))-(SUM(d.cantidad_dist)))) as tot
  FROM venta v
    INNER JOIN detalle_venta dv ON dv.idventa = v.idventa
    INNER JOIN distribucion ON dv.idventa = d.id_venta
  WHERE v.idplaza=7 AND d.id_plaza=7 GROUP BY dv.idarticulo AND d.id_articulo
```

> me dice error "La columna 'd.id_dist' en field list es desconocida" y esa columna es la id principal de distribuciones, **por favor alguien que me ayude a salir de esto.**

Comment: ...INNER JOIN distribucion ON...
Te falta una d después de distribución, intentas usar su alias pero nunca lo asignaste!

Comment: Hola amigo revisando tu consulta veo varios errores, como comenta Benito  te hace falta asignar el alias a la tabla distribución, sin embargo corrigiendo ese error también veo  que en el  WHERE v.idcliente=7  el campo idcliente no hace parte de la tabla venta, y la función de SUM contiene un error.
Otra cosa no me queda clara la estructura de tu tabla distribución. Puedes detallar un poco mas tu problema para poderte ayudar?

Comment: Gracias hermano... pero ya probé y me da otro error que no esperaba al parecer es error al aplicar la suma dentro de cada suma. En error dice "inválido en uso de función en grupo" pero pruebo quiosco la suma de cada columna y dejo solo la resta de los primeros datos y me la ejecuta.... SUM((SUM(dv.cantidad))-(SUM(d.cantidad_dist))) as tot y al quitarle las simas internan queda SUM((dv.cantidad)-(d.cantidad_dist)) as tot esto si lo ejecuta pero no las sumas que podría hacer... Gracias

Comment: No mira ya le modifique esa falla de idcliente por idplaza y les agregue el alias pro persiste el error

Comment: Debes modificar la pregunta y agregar por ejemplo la estructura de tus tablas que genera tu programa  para que te podamos ayudar